# Drawing the basin boundaries

Tags: plotting, graphics

In my case, I need to use the following [data file](http://web.archive.org/web/20200229053801if_/http://download1519.mediafire.com/3jwgvozn3k1g/570pix0l0h20xxy/LGs.dat)

Let's plot the basins

```
m = ReadList["LGs.dat", Number, RecordLists -> True];
getColor[m_List, i_Integer] := 
  Module[{s = m[[i, 3]]}, 
  Which[s == 4, Darker[Green], s == 6, Blue, s == 8, Cyan, s == 10, 
  Orange, s == 12, Purple, s == 14, Red, True, Black]];
data = Table[{PointSize[0.005], getColor[m, i], 
Point[{m[[i, 1]], m[[i, 2]]}]}, {i, 1, Length[m]}];
S0 = Graphics[data];
P0 = Show[{S0}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"α", "δ"}, FrameStyle -> Thick, 
  RotateLabel -> False, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 22], 
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

My question is: how can I draw a black solid line, thus highlighting the basin boundaries?

**EDIT**

Following @yarchik 's suggestion I get the following output

[image]

As you can see, the boundary lines are very ugly. Is there a way to obtain nice, smooth solid lines inicating the basin boundaries?

Answer (score 5):

### Out-of-box solution (*left figure*):

```
ListContourPlot[m[[All, 1 ;; 3]], 
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed], 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 ImageSize -> Small, 
 FrameLabel -> {"α", "δ"}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image][image]

This is pure esthetics consideration that the contours are dashed, the image is small, the theme is monochrome. It is fully customizable within `ListContourPlot` as shown below for different colors.

### Explicitly specify the `ColorFunction`(*right figure*)

```
ListContourPlot[m[[All, 1 ;; 3]], 
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed], 
 ColorFunction -> (Which[# < 5, Darker[Green], # < 7, Blue, # < 9, 
     Cyan, # < 11, Orange, # < 13, Purple, # < 15, Red, True, 
     Black] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ImageSize -> Small, 
 FrameLabel -> {"α", "δ"}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

Comment: Is there a way to control the choice of colors for each basin?

Comment: Could you please indicate how can I define the custom color function?

Comment: See also my edit.